# Methodology - Check a balance before allowing next transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for the best way to architect simple SMS billing functionality using SQL tables.

I have a mechanism by which SMS will be purchased into a table: e.g +1000.

I will have transactions that are executing and will decrease by -1 at a time as SMSs are utilized.

I need to have a process that first checks that the balance is above 1 before a transaction is processed.

My concern here is that before every -1 SMS transactions i need to do a lookup on the balance and then only process the SMS transaction if the balance is above +1 which could have a detrimental impact on performance.

What is a 'performant' way to achieved this? A 'running total balance' something like the below?

```
TID  amt  balance user_Id
--- ----- ------- -------
1    +100   100     a
2    -1      99     a
3    -1      98     a
4    -1      97     a
5    -1      96     a
```

One query to check the running total value, and if it is positive then to execute a running balance update and continue?

How well would this scale? This table could potentially have hundreds of such transactions executing per second.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your quesiton with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the running total as:

```
select t.*, sum(amt) over (partition by user_id order by tid) as balance
from t;
```

Whether this meets your performance needs is uncertain.  You may need to add a trigger to maintain the balance in each `user` record, so you can readily access the latest value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to answer, and it depends on many trade-offs.

Hundreds of transactions / second is not a huge load, and I would start by building this the "clean" way without denormalizing.

In very general terms as long as your database can use an index to search, calculating the SUM from many transactions will not be noticeably slower than reading it from one record.

Pre-computing may actually be slower in the real world. Using a trigger to update the precomputed value may be slower (an extra lookup/transaction), and updating a running total maybe slower due extra lookup and calculation effort.

I would build a load test environment, and keep optimizing against real, observable performance challenges, rather than optimizing in advance.